# JavaFX: ComboBox using Object property

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, combobox

Lets say I have a class:

```
public class Dummy {
    private String name;
    private String someOtherProperty;

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

I have an ArrayList of this class `ArrayList<Dummy> dummyList;`

Can I create a JavaFX ComboBox with the Object name property as selection options without creating a new `ArrayList<String>` with the object names?

Pseudocode:

```
ObservableList<Dummy> dummyO = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dummyList);
final ComboBox combo = new ComboBox(dummyO); // -> here dummyO.name?
```

(Optional) Ideally, while the name should be displayed, when an option has been selected, the `combo.getValue()` should return me the reference of the selected Dummy and not only the name. Is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a custom `cellFactory` to display the items in a way that suits your needs:

```
ComboBox<Dummy> comboBox = ...

Callback<ListView<Dummy>, ListCell<Dummy>> factory = lv -> new ListCell<Dummy>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Dummy item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? "" : item.getName());
    }

};

comboBox.setCellFactory(factory);
comboBox.setButtonCell(factory.call(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the ComboBox you're referring to is this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html. As `getValue()` is `public`, you can do:

```
public class MyComboBox<T> extends ComboBox<T> {
  private final Dummy dummy;
  public MyComboBox(Dummy dummy) {
    this.dummy = dummy;
  }
  public T getValue() {
    return dummy.getName();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While I do not believe you have directly answered my question of how to display a property in the ComboBox and not the object itself, creating a custom ComboBox class is a good suggestion!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This would replace the type of object returned from `getValue` to `String`, which would lead to a `ClassCastException` in many cases. Furthermore you're returning the name of the same `Dummy` regardless of the values selected in the `ComboBox`. And last but not least `getValue()` is `final` and thus cannot be overriden.