# how to get model id from javafx combobox

Tags: java, javafx

```
if (validateInput()) {
    Product product = productModel.getProduct(productBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()+1);
    Supplier supplier = supplierModel.getSupplier(supplierBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() + 1);
    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(quantityField.getText());
    double price = Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText());
    double total = quantity * price;
    Purchase purchase = new Purchase(
            product,
            supplier,
            quantity,
            price,
            total
    );
}
```

This my code snippet this `productBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()+1`
 work find when in database has value id = 1,2,3,4 in sequence but it show null product when value of id =3,4 not in sequence . please Help I am new to javafx

Comment: Just add a property to your `Product` class and use `productBox.getValue().getId()` (assuming you use a `ComboBox<Product>`) There's little reason not to use the model class as item class for the `ComboBox` here...

Comment: @fabian thanks for your quick reply please can you explain a little bit more because I am new to JavaFX thing how can we get selected model id if `productBox.getValue().getId()`

Comment: Assuming you use a `ComboBox<Product> productBox`, `productBox.getValue()` returns the `Product` (making the detour to `productModel` a bit pointless). If you don't want to use a complete `Product` instance for every item, you could still create a `IdValue` class containing both the id+a value...

Comment: If you don't know how to display the correct of the item class in the `ComboBox`, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41208128/2991525

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.